# Force System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser open in standard mode

Tags: window, webbrowser-control, quirks-mode

I'm developing a client windows form application. the application must browse URLs provided by servers in a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control.
The problem is when Navigating Document Mode is set to Quirks and a "Http Status 403" is shown instead of the requested Page.
How to force webBrowser to open in standard mode without changing the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation) feature control got your application's executable filename?

Remember that the default values for a number of [feature controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx) vary between IE and applications hosting the webbrowser control.  If you see different behavior when rendering the same content, it's possible that a feature control needs to be adjusted.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: I don't want to change  registry values !!

Comment: The registry may be your best approach.  You can try serving appropriate x-ua-compatible header (`content="ie=edge"`) within the page or by the web server.  You may also need update your <!DOCTYPE> to use the HTML5 doctype and (if you're serving the pages from a file system of some sort) may also need to add an MOTW to force Internet zone.  If this isn't working, please provide more specific details about what you've tried and what you're seeing instead.  Note that the registry changes I mentioned earlier may be the only approach, depending on design, implementation, and circumstances.